# is it good decision to upgrade to ssd?

Tags: laptop, processor, pc, hard-disk, ssd

I have a laptop having 4gb RAM with i3 5th generation, and does not have M2 slot but has CD drive. My laptop speed is very slow now so I decided to add 128gb SSD to it. The service center told me that since it has CD drive they need to add something called Caddy drive and place SSD inside it. My friend suggest not to upgrade my laptop to SSD and it will not boost the speed. I am confused right now please anyone help me what to do?

Comment: If you don't have ssd already, and ssd will significantly speed up ANY computer

Comment: Slow in what way? SSD will speed up boot time and any operation with intensive disk access. But for an application running primarily from memory, CPU and memory speed are more important. You need to be more specific on the speed concerns.

Comment: You could probably also replace your existing internal 2.5" SATA HDD with an SSD, and still retain your optical drive.

Your friend is clueless. If you're currently using an HDD, and SSD will be an *enormous* upgrade. HDD PCs are completely unusable by modern standards.

Comment: I agree towe, I installed Windows 11 to test stuff on a hard drive because I ran out of ssd's that are not in use. Its really slomo.

Comment: Yes, adding an SSD is worthwhile. I've done this on my own elderly PC to good effect. If you're running Windows on your laptop another problem is that 4 GB RAM isn't enough for good performance. If you can upgrade to 8 or 16 GB you'll get a performance boost on top of adding an SSD. crucial.com has a memory scanner that can tell you what memory upgrades will fit your laptop. (You can buy from them or get the same specification of memory from someone else.)

Answer (score 3):

> My laptop speed is very slow now so I decided to add 128gb SSD to it.
> ...
> My friend suggest not to upgrade my laptop to SSD and it will not boost the speed.

Your friend might be right if you're just *adding* an SSD. You need to *replace* your HDD with an SSD to see the full benefit.

The drive that Windows is installed on is the drive that is being used continuously by the computer. If that drive is an SSD it will be noticeably faster than the HDD you had before. If you just add an SSD as a D: drive you can still speed up specific programs that are installed on that drive.

It's not a bad idea to have both an SSD and a HDD in your computer; But make sure Windows is installed on the SSD.